# Proving implication on well ordered set implies AC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following statement:

> If $A$ is a well-ordered set such that every nonempty subset of $A$ has a maximal element, then $A$ is finite.

I am trying to prove that this statement implies the axiom of choice.  I'm somewhat confused on how to approach this question without having the ability to well order sets.

Comment: AC is equivalent to the statement that every set can be well-ordered.

Comment: Well-ordering means every nonempty subset has a *minimum* element, not necessarily a maximum element. The natural numbers are well-ordered, for example.

Comment: "Given that finite sets are the only sets that [can] be [provably] well ordered" -- in the absence of AC, I guess you mean. *What are you actually supposed to prove?* It seems you're asked to prove AC from the well-ordering principle (**every** set can be wellordered, not just finite ones).

Comment: What's the question? "Well ordered set implies AC" is not a proposition, in any language. A wellordered set is not a statement and can't "imply" anything.

Comment: @Brian: He is asked to prove some equivalence between AC and a statement which is itself an equivalence. I should know, I wrote the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Haha, ok :) The question here is confusing because that "statement which is itself an equivalence" is nowhere in sight.

Comment: If Eric's edit expresses your question, then this is wrong - the statement is provable in ZF alone, and doesn't require any choice.

Comment: (@Eric: Thanks for the edit) Now I can point out the difficulty. The phrasing of the implication is wrong. Go back to the exercise sheet and read the question again.

Comment: (And let me repeat what I wrote below Eric's deleted answer. It's impossible to give a hint to this question, because the solution is extremely short. Except perhaps that the solution is extremely, short, that's a hint.)

Comment: And there I was, waiting for @AsafKaragila to show up and elaborate on the problem - and it turns out he only gives us an Epiminedean hint ...

Comment: @Hagen: I would be glad to elaborate, but the problem is quite fresh. So waiting a few days to make sure the students actually had time to work it out seemed like the better idea.